# DataTable - Do a pivot

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, pivot

On a specific date related dataset like this :

```
[
  {date:"2017", "Column1": "A", "Column2": "B", "Column3": "C"},
  {date:"2018", "Column1": "1", "Column2": "2", "Column3": "3"}...
]
```

I can't find anything in documentation on how to do a pivot on the table from this form :

`2017    A    B    C
    2018    1    2    3`

to this one :

`2017  2018
    A     1
    B     2
    C     3`

Comment: Are you referring jQuery's DataTables plugin ? you should add it to tags if so

Comment: Yes. I don't know how neither why, but it was deleted from the tag list.
I just tried to add it again but it doesn't show up..